# Python: Pandas, fastest way to count occurrences of substring in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has approximately 100,000 rows. "sequence" column in the dataframe has some long string as its value. I basically want to calculate the occurrence of substring in the "sequence" column with overlap **(i.e. if the value is aaaaaa, and the substring is aa, then the frequency should be 5, not 3)**.

Below is the reproducible code that is similar to the actual code.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import itertools
import time
from random import choice

# generate 100,000 random strings of fixed size for demo purpose
alphabet = "abcdefghijk"
str_list = []

for i in range(100000):
     str_list.append(''.join(choice(alphabet) for i in range(100)))
# make pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sequence'], data=str_list)

# get a list of substrings to count its frequency in the dataframe
# for the sake of demo, make substrings from "alphabet" with length of 3
# actual application can have up to substrings of length 5 (i.e. 11^5 substrings)
words = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3))]

# calculate frequency of words in the dataframe
for word in words:
    tic = time.time()
    df['frequency'] = df['sequence'].apply(lambda x: len(re.findall('(?={0})'.format(word), x)))
    print("{}s took for one iteration".format(time.time() - tic))
```

Note that Pandas built-in function, "pd.Series.str.count", would count the occurrence of substring **without** overlaps, so I had to use apply in conjunction with regular expression.

The problem is, on my computer it takes ~0.5 seconds to calculate frequency per each substring, and since there are 11^3 to 11^5 number of substrings, it could take up to 80,000 seconds (or 11 hours) in the worst case.

It seems that lambda operation is slowing down the computational time since it has to be compiled in python instead of cython (which is inarguably faster than python), but I don't know how else to do this.

I was wondering if there are ways to speed up this operation?

p.s. I am using Python 3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Lets step back for a second:
With your method you're invoking a `lambda` function for every row in the `Series`. Upon invocation, it has to compile a regex pattern and us it to search 1 string. You'll loose some time in the lambda invocations, and in the regex compilation.

Speeding up the `lambda` invocations can be done by not using `lambda`! Use vectorized methods instead. You already found `Series.str.count` but there is also `Series.str.findall`, which does the same as your `lambda`.
Speed gained: **+/- 1.15x faster**. (mean execution time per word from 0.167 to 0.127 seconds)

The real problem is the regex. Compiling regex is inefficient, so we should try to limit the number of times we do it. One way to do this is by batching together the "words" you're trying to find into a single regex expression. In the example below I've set the batch size to 100, but you can tune this of course.
Speed gained: **+/- 33x faster**. (mean execution time per word from 0.167 to 0.005).

```py
import itertools
import re
import string
import time
from random import choice

import pandas as pd

# Generate 100,000 random strings of fixed size for demo purpose
alphabet: list[str] = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:11])

# Limit the number of samples to 100 for demo purpose
limit = 100

# Make pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["sequence"],
    data=["".join(choice(alphabet) for _ in range(100)) for _ in range(100000)],
)

# Get a list of substrings to count its frequency in the dataframe for
# the sake of demo, make substrings from "alphabet" with length of 3
# actual application can have up to substrings of length 5 (i.e. 11^5
# substrings)
words: list[str] = ["".join(p) for p in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=3)]

# ORIGINAL METHOD
# ======================================================================
df["frequency_original"] = 0
times_original: list[float] = []
start = time.time()
for word in words[:limit]:
    tic = time.time()
    df["frequency_original"] = df["frequency_original"] + df["sequence"].apply(
        lambda x: len(re.findall("(?={0})".format(word), x))
    )
    times_original.append(time.time() - tic)

# Calculate and show statistics
mean_time_original = sum(times_original) / len(times_original)
total_time_original = time.time() - start
print(
    f"Mean time for original method: {mean_time_original} (total time: {total_time_original})"
)

# USING VECTORISED METHOD
# ======================================================================
df["frequency_str_findall"] = 0
times_new: list[float] = []
start = time.time()
for word in words[:limit]:
    tic = time.time()
    df["frequency_str_findall"] = df["frequency_str_findall"] + df[
        "sequence"
    ].str.findall(f"(?={word})").apply(len)
    times_new.append(time.time() - tic)

# Calculate and show statistics
mean_time_new = sum(times_new) / len(times_new)
total_time_new = time.time() - start
print(
    f"Mean time for vectorized method: {mean_time_new} (total time: {total_time_new})"
)

# USING VECTORISED METHOD WITH BATCHING
# ======================================================================
times_new_batch: list[float] = []
df["frequency_str_findall_batch"] = 0
batch_size = 100
start = time.time()
for index in range(0, len(words[:limit]), batch_size):
    tic = time.time()
    pattern = (
        "(?=" + "|".join([word for word in words[index : index + batch_size]]) + ")"
    )
    df["frequency_str_findall_batch"] = df["frequency_str_findall_batch"] + df[
        "sequence"
    ].str.findall(pattern).apply(len)
    times_new_batch.append(time.time() - tic)

# Calculate and show statistics
mean_time_new_batch = sum(times_new_batch) / len(times_new_batch) / batch_size
total_time_new_batch = time.time() - start
print(
    f"Mean time for batched method: {mean_time_new_batch} (total time: {total_time_new_batch})"
)

# Show that the methods are equivalent
assert df["frequency_original"].equals(df["frequency_str_findall"])
assert df["frequency_str_findall"].equals(df["frequency_str_findall_batch"])
```

```bash
Mean time for original method: 0.16653778791427612 (total time: 16.65402317047119)
Mean time for vectorized method: 0.14487099170684814 (total time: 14.487332344055176)
Mean time for batched method: 0.005008835792541504 (total time: 0.5008978843688965)
```